# Does high pressure make drag on a wing?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, drag, aerodynamics

Say you have a plate facing the airflow right over a wing. Not attached, but just right over it. If flow separation and drag on the rear side of the plate (rear meaning the trailing edge of a wing) wasn’t a thing, would there be any drag at all?

Basically does any drag come from the high pressure in front of the plate? (It would make sense for high pressure to make drag if the plate was attached to the wing, but in this instance it’s not) I know that drag comes from the rear side making turbulence and separating flow, but if you were to disregard that, would there be any drag?

So to summarize, if the drag effects from the rear side of the plate wasn’t a thing, would there be any drag?

Comment: Also when I say “drag” I mean drag for the airfoil, not the plate.

Comment: This should answer your question.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)